# Associating a variable with a tmptable

Tags: t-sql

```
declare @count int = 0

while @count< 5
BEGIN
IF '#temptable%' = (SELECT name
                    FROM tempdb.sys.columns
                    WHERE column_name = 'Butter')
set @table1 = 'temptable%'
else '#temptable%' = (SELECT name
                      FROM tempdb.sys.columns
                      WHERE column_name = 'Parrot')
set @table2 = 'temptable%'
set @count= @count+ 1
END
```

So I have five temporary tables with the name `#temptable1`, `#temptable2`, etc. and would like to distinguish the them from each other and set them to a variable depending on the unique column_name (ie. `#temptable1` will be associated with the variable `@table1`).

So is there a way I can call `@table1` and then have it return `#temptable1`?

Comment: What do you mean by calling @table1 and returning #temptable?

Comment: I have to make temporary tables that hold the column names of flat files.  I need to query the temp tables with the unique column names associated with the flat tile and I would like to set the variable name to something like @table1

Comment: May be you mean somethin like this?
`CREATE TABLE #ttt(id int)
DECLARE @table1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = '#ttt'
EXEC('select * from ' + @table1)`